# Clicking on suggestion results and filling text box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a search box that gives you a list of suggested results based on data from a MySql database. If the user types A and the words `Apple` and `Animal` are in the databse, then the suggestion box will show both results. Currently, there is no way for me to click one of the results and have it fill the text box, and no matter what I try and do, I can't seem to get it to work. Currently, I'm working with something that looks like this:

```
  echo '<script type ="text/javascript">'; 

  echo 'function textFill(){';
  echo ' var txt=document.getElementById("userInput").value= <li onclick ="textFill(this.value)">' .$matched[$count].'</li>'; //Suggestion results
  echo '}';
  echo"</script>";
 }
```

I'll be honest, I'm not sure if this is even the right path to be going, but I found a few examples that were vaguely similar to this, so that's that direction I went with it. With this set up, the suggestion box doesn't even display, but if I take away the `echo '<script type ='text/javascript>'` it will display the results plus the whole line of `getElement` code. How would I go about getting this to work properly? I can show more code if necessary.

EDIT:
I'm providing more code to show more of my PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['userInput'])){
   $value = $_GET['userInput']; //assign the value
   strtolower($value);
  }else{
   echo "no input";
  }
//Select query

  $sql = "SELECT Device_type FROM Device WHERE Device_type LIKE '%".$value."%';";


  if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
//Store the result in an array list[]

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     $list[] = $row['Device_type'];
    }
   }else{
//set a null value to list[] if no result to prevent error

    $list[] = "";
   }
  }

  if(!empty($value)){
   if($matched = preg_grep('~'.$value.'~i', $list)){
   $count = 0;
   echo '<ul>';
    while($count < sizeOf($list)){
     if(isset($matched[$count])){

      echo '<li > ' .$matched[$count].'</li>';

     }
     $count++;
    }
   echo '</ul>';
   echo json_encode($data);
   }else{
    echo "No result";
   }
```

Comment: Did you read the error console, revealed by pressing F12 in your browser?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes The error is Uncaught `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. I have 2 pages, one has my input textbox and another that handles the database connection and query. I have `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>` referenced in the `<head>` section of the first page that houses my input box, do I need to have it on the database connection/query page as well?

Comment: Libraries need to be included standalone in every *page* that uses them. If you load this code in an iframe, that's a new page. If you load this via Ajax (as I suspect you don't) it's not. However, all JS processing halts on the first fatal error, and that is one for sure.

Comment: You need to add JQuery not Jquery UI

Comment: I just changed the address to `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` and added this to both pages. The error is gone from the console, but the results are still the same. When I type in a letter, the suggestion box doesn't appear.

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have following files served with your web server.

```
|- search.php
|- index.html
```

In your index.html file:

```
<!-- loading JQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- code for capturing user input, sending it to server (search.php) and upon receiving suggestions populating them under the search box -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchbox').keyup(function() { // upon every key up when user is typing
        $('#suggestions').html(''); // clear if any previous suggestions

        var input = $(this).val();

        $.getJSON( // sending a GET request via AJAX expecting a JSON response
            'search.php', // to this URL where the PHP file is
            {
                searchQuery: input // with the text user typed in
            },
            function(data) { // upon receiving a response
                $(data).each(function() { // iterate through the suggestions data received as JSON
                    var suggestion = '<option value=' + this + '>'; // create an <option> element with the each suggestion
                    $('#suggestions').append(suggestion); // and append it to the suggestions <datalist>
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<!-- search form -->
<input id="searchbox" name="searchbox" type="search" list="suggestions">
<datalist id="suggestions">
    <!-- suggestions will be populated here when user is typing -->
</datalist>
```

Your search.php file:

```
$term = $_GET['searchQuery'];
$suggestions = [];

if(isset($term) && !empty($term)){
    $servername = "your_db_servername"; // Ex: localhost
    $username = "your_db_username"; // Ex: root
    $password = "your_db_password";
    $dbname = "your_db_name";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if(!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT Device_type FROM Device WHERE Device_type LIKE '". $term ."%';"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($suggestions, $row["Device_type"]);
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

    echo json_encode($suggestions);
}
```

However you should note that sending AJAX request on evey keyup event can be quite overwhelming especially if the user is typing fast.

To make it more efficient it is a good idea to debounce the keyup event.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js "></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchbox').keyup($.debounce( 250, function() { // act upon keyup events every 250 milliseconds when user is typing 
        $('#suggestions').html('');

        var input = $(this).val();

        $.getJSON(
            'search.php',
            { searchQuery: input },
            function(data) {
                $(data).each(function() {
                    var suggestion = '<option value=' + this + '>';
                    $('#suggestions').append(suggestion);
                });
            }
        );
    }));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm having trouble finding the right placement for `if(isset($_GET['searchQuery']) && !empty($_GET['searchQuery'])){` in my PHP file. Much of this is very new to me, even a lot of this code that I already have has been put together from online examples, so some of it I don't fully understand just yet. I have updated my question with more information about my PHP file. Everything I do either provides no results or still results in the suggestions being unclickable.

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 I updated the answer with full PHP code you need.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer, but I seem to be too dense to follow simple instructions. I've tried both incorporating your answer into my code, and flat out copying your code and replacing what I have, but I can't seem to get either to work. When i use the just the code you provided, I don't even get a drop down with suggested results.

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 Sorry to hear that. I tested the above code I provided in my answer locally and it is working. Few things to check: 1) Any javascript errors in index.html when searching (check console)? 2) Does <datalist> get populated with <option>s at all (view page source)? 3) Does getting data from MySQL db work?